# Can't change .properties file path on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, properties

I was given a project from NetBeans to work on. I imported it on eclipse and it's ready.
When on run it gives me a null pointer exception error because Eclipse can't find it's original properties file (on another computer's local address). It's very easy to change the path on NetBeans but I can't find the same option on Eclipse the project properties window.

As i found on the web, Eclipse should be searching for it, by default, in the src folder, and there it happens to be my new config file.

There should be some kind of config file where this local address is written but right now I can't find it. not even Google can help me :(

I am using the class propertiesPath to retrieve the address:

```
private String propertiesPath = Utility.getPropertiesPath();
```

this is the error I get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \home\***\Java Project\****\datacommunication.properties (Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \home\***\Java Project\****\datacommunication.properties (Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato)
feb 09, 2016 2:40:47 PM DBlinker1Thread run
GRAVE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Communication.LogsManager.logEvent(LogsManager.java:48)
    at Communication.DataBaseManager.loadDriver(DataBaseManager.java:79)
    at DBlinker1Thread.init(DBlinker1Thread.java:96)
    at DBlinker1Thread.run(DBlinker1Thread.java:42)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Utility class gives the wrong path,
change the Utility class to include the correct path.

If you can't change the Utility class,
I suggest that you stop using it and implement the getPropertiesPath method in something that you can change.

Comment: I am using a communication.utility class. I was trying to search for a documentation but I think it is done by somebody here. That's why

Comment: @Freddy Consider including the actual classname (the one that includes the package) in your question.

Comment: Communication.Utility? I am using default package. this is just a test.

Comment: Change the class to do what you need or replace it.